# Javascript reemplazar letras por caracteres especiales

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Actualmente tengo este código para enviar mensajes y que se impriman en la pagina html

```
<script>

const msgBox = document.querySelector('#msgBox');
function onKeyDown(evt) {
 
  if(evt.keyCode === 13) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}

function sendMessage() {
  console.log('Mensaje Enviado: ', msgBox.value);
  msgBox.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div id="two">${msgBox.value}</div>`);
}

function clearMessageBox() {
  msgBox.value = '';
}
</script>
<style>
textarea {
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border-color: #474747;
  color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que al escribir por ejemplo ''Hola a todos'' y darle enter

me lo reemplace y muestre con los caracteres especiales ''  ''.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo lograr esto?, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías crear un par de arreglos, uno con los caracteres "normales" para buscar y otro con los que se deben remplazar. Se recomienda [normalizar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) la cadena y convertir a minúsculas para tratar de cubrir la mayor cantidad de caracteres posible.

```js
// Se puede crear un arreglo a partir de la cadena
let search = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
// Solo tomé algunos caracteres, completa el arreglo
let replace = ['', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '', 'i', 'j', 'k', '', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', '', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function changeChars(msg) {
    // Eliminar tildes
    msg = msg.normalize('NFKD');
    // Convertir en minúsculas
    msg = msg.toLowerCase();
    // Recorrer todos los caracteres
    search.forEach((char, index) => {
        // Remplazar cada caracter en la cadena
        msg = msg.replaceAll(char, replace[index]);
    });
    return msg;
}


console.log(changeChars('Hola a todos'));
// Probando caracteres con tilde
console.log(changeChars('Hòlä a tódos; hasta mañana'));
```

Seguramente vas a tener que agregar números y algunos símbolo, pero no creo que sea tan complicado, siempre que los arreglos tengan la misma cantidad de elementos y en el mismo orden.